# How to append a plain HTMLElement to a React Component

Tags: reactjs

I am quite new to React, so pardon if I mix concepts here. I have a React project and I have this index.html (showing body only)

```
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="external">
      <div>
        <p>Test Paragraph</p>
        <div>
          <p>Another Child</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And I need to move the "external" div into my React components. I have this App.js:

```
function App() {
  var ext_holder = React.createElement('span', {});
  
  var page = React.createElement(
    'div',
    {},
    React.createElement(
      'div',
      {},
      <p>Hello World</p>
    ),
    ext_holder,
    React.createElement(
      'div',
      {},
      <p>Foo Bar</p>
    )
  );
  
  return page;
}
```

How could I move the "external" div that's in the index.html, into the "ext_holder" React component?

I could do it setting the HTML dangerously in ext_holder, but then when I delete the original HTMLElement (remember I want to move it, not have it twice), I get null pointers for the innerHTML. Any other attempt to move it displays an error that an HTMLElement is not a React component.

I tried getElementbyId and then set the innerHTML but that throws an error when deleting the original. I tried appending the children to a React component but that throws errors as well

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add the external div to `index.html` before your bundle takes over
I'm afraid that not going to happen with react! you need to use SSR to get an html with stuff dynamically rendered on it.
And if you're not, then you really don't need to create elements like that in react. remove the external div from your `index.html` and in your app.js

```js
function App() {
  const some_var = "hello some var"
  return <div>
    <div id="external">
      <div>
        <p>{some_var}</p>
        <div>
          <p>Another Child</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

There are very rare cases that manipulating `dom` directly in react is actually needed.

Comment: "you need to use SSR to get an html with stuff dynamically rendered on it". This is absolutely untrue.

Comment: @possum. So there is a way to render stuff on `index.html` before javascript bundles are loaded in reactjs? good to know. please provide the documentations for that!